# Decomposition of the Regular Q8 Module

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

For a worksheet we were asked to find the decomposition of the regular $Q_8$ module into a direct sum of simple modules. This isn't me asking for help on homework though, the problem is that I already have the solutions back and I don't understand/agree with them. To clarify, $Q_8 = \{\pm1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ and the regular module is $\mathbb{C}[Q_8]$.

Now I know that the number of simple G-modules equals the number of conjugacy classes of G, so I thought there would be five simple modules: 4 1-dimensional and 1 2-dimensional. As I understand it, the decomposition should be of the form $\mathbb{C}[Q_8] \cong V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus V_3 \oplus V_4 \oplus 2 V_5$.
However the solutions list 6 modules in the decomposition, two of them being two dimensional.

I have emailed my lecturer about this and he said that there are 6 modules because the two 2-dimensional ones are isomorphic as modules but not as vector spaces. I don't really understand what he was trying to say.

So my first question is, which way is right? And if there are indeed 6 modules in the decomposition, why are there only 5 simple representations on a character table for $Q_8$?

Also less important, if anyone could explain how you actually *find* the 5/6 representations, or link me to a good explanation, that would be appreciated, as again the solutions weren't clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is. You have six modules in your decomposition, and two of them are two-dimensional, so that agrees with the solution. The underlying vector space has dimension 8, and the direct summands have dimensions 1,1,1,2,2, which add up to 8.

Comment: I have to find the modules, so lets say I find the first five, $V_1$ through $V_5$. Is that enough to give the decomposition in the form above with $V_5$ appearing twice, or do I need to find a separate module $V_6$?